# 2 Pagers showing for Views Block

Tags: views

I created a Custom View block in  Drupal 7 which it is simply pulling random "Did you know Tips" for visitors. I created a mini pager for the block to allow visitors to toggle through them (Ajax enable as well for the asynchronous refresh of the block)

Everything is working accordingly except one tiny issue... I have 2 Pagers on my home page??? One is the mini pager under the block which is desired, but an additional Full pager is created at the bottom of my main page. Oddly, it's only found on the main page!!! No other nodes pages have this issue.

It seems that the behavior is along the lines that the additional pager is being "promoted to the front page" however, the content type has that excluded. Is there a way to hide this additional pager in template.php / views-view.tpl.php? Perhaps I missed something along the way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue just happened to me there's a field on the pager detail screen that allows you to set an id for the pager. This is usually set to 0. I updated the id and the second full pager at the bottom of the page went away. 
Wanted to post this in case anyone finds this page as I did.

Answer (score 0):

In investigating this issue further, I resided to installing the [Views Litepager](https://drupal.org/project/views_litepager) module as it's an increase in performance and it resolved my issue as well with the 2 pagers.